# Grouping by continuous and no continuous date in a dict

Tags: python

I  have the following dict and I am required to group the continuous and non-continuous date in the following order:

```
input_data = {
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 1): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 3): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 4): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 5): 9,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 6): 10,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 7): 10,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 8): 10,
}
```

The goal is to bundle as long the values are equal and the dates are continuous, i.e., the output should look like this

```
[{'from_date': '2019-01-01', 'val': 2, 'to_date': '2019-01-01'}, {'from_date': '2019-01-03', 'val': 2, 'to_date': '2019-01-04'}, {'from_date': '2019-01-05', 'val': 9, 'to_date': '2019-01-05'}, {'from_date': '2019-01-06', 'val': 10, 'to_date': '2019-01-08'}]
```

I have implemented a hack but it is not clean. Any advise or ideas with regards to a cleaner implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: How should we know what is a cleaner implementation than yours if we don't see your implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary as a grouping mechanism. The key to that grouping dictionary would the date's delta to its relative position.

```
import datetime
input_data = {
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 1): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 3): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 4): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 5): 9,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 6): 10,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 7): 10,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 8): 10,
}
```

Grouping:

```
groups = dict()
for i,(d,n) in enumerate(input_data.items()):
    groups.setdefault(d.toordinal()-i,{'from':d,'val':n})['to'] = d
groups = list(groups.values())
```

Output:

```
print(groups)

[
{'from':datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'val':2,  'to':datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)},
{'from':datetime.date(2019, 1, 3), 'val':2,  'to':datetime.date(2019, 1, 4)},
{'from':datetime.date(2019, 1, 5), 'val':9,  'to':datetime.date(2019, 1, 5)},
{'from':datetime.date(2019, 1, 6), 'val':10, 'to':datetime.date(2019, 1, 8)}
]
```

*I'm assuming the dictionary's order is chronological. If not you can sort the items used by for-loop: `enumerate(sorted(input_data.items())`*

The trick to the key is that the difference between the iteration index and the date will be the same for consecutive dates but would change as soon as there is a gap.

If the value can change during a span of consecutive dates and you want that to form separate groups, then a value grouping scheme should be added:

```
input_data = {  datetime.date(2019, 1, 1): 2,
                datetime.date(2019, 1, 2): 2,
                datetime.date(2019, 1, 3): 2,
                datetime.date(2019, 1, 4): 3,
                datetime.date(2019, 1, 5): 3,
                datetime.date(2019, 1, 6): 3,
                datetime.date(2019, 1, 7): 2,
                datetime.date(2019, 1, 8): 2,
                datetime.date(2019, 1, 9): 2,
                datetime.date(2019, 1, 10): 2 }

groups, g, p = dict(), 0, None
for i,(d,n) in enumerate(input_data.items()):
    if p != n: g,p = g+1,n
    groups.setdefault((d.toordinal()-i,g),{'from':d,'val':n})['to'] = d
groups = list(groups.values())

[
{'from': datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'val': 2, 'to': datetime.date(2019, 1, 3)}
{'from': datetime.date(2019, 1, 4), 'val': 3, 'to': datetime.date(2019, 1, 6)}
{'from': datetime.date(2019, 1, 7), 'val': 2, 'to': datetime.date(2019, 1, 10)}
]
```

Comment: T- Thank you. I tried it but it fails. eg  It fails for the input input_data = { datetime.date(2019, 1, 1): 2, datetime.date(2019, 1, 2): 2, datetime.date(2019, 1, 3): 2, datetime.date(2019, 1, 4): 3, datetime.date(2019, 1, 5): 3, datetime.date(2019, 1, 6): 3, datetime.date(2019, 1, 7): 2, datetime.date(2019, 1, 8): 2, datetime.date(2019, 1, 9): 2, datetime.date(2019, 1, 10): 2, } It should be grouping 1-3,4-6 and 7-10.

Comment: Did you use the second form (with value change grouping scheme)?  It is giving your expected result for me.

Comment: Yes I did. This is what the output is
[{'to': datetime.date(2019, 1, 10), 'from': datetime.date(2019, 1, 10), 'val': 2}, {'to': datetime.date(2019, 1, 8), 'from': datetime.date(2019, 1, 7), 'val': 2}, {'to': datetime.date(2019, 1, 3), 'from': datetime.date(2019, 1, 3), 'val': 2}, {'to': datetime.date(2019, 1, 4), 'from': datetime.date(2019, 1, 4), 'val': 3},....

Comment: T- Tried with the following code
def bundle_data(input_data):
    groups, g, p = dict(), 0, None
    for i, (d, n) in enumerate(input_data.items()):
        if p != n: g, p = g + 1, n
        groups.setdefault((d.toordinal() - i, g), {'from': d, 'val': n})['to'] = d
    groups = list(groups.values())
    return groups

Comment: It looks like the original dictionary is not in chronological order (or you're using an older version of Python where dictionaries are not ordered).   If that is the case add a sort in the for-loop: `enumerate(sorted(input_data.items())
`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of those times where asking "Have you tried using pandas?" seems a reasonable response, especially if you have a lot of data.

```
In [56]: import pandas as pd

In [57]: import datetime

In [58]: input_data = {
    ...:     datetime.date(2019, 1, 1): 2,
    ...:     datetime.date(2019, 1, 3): 2,
    ...:     datetime.date(2019, 1, 4): 2,
    ...:     datetime.date(2019, 1, 5): 9,
    ...:     datetime.date(2019, 1, 6): 10,
    ...:     datetime.date(2019, 1, 7): 10,
    ...:     datetime.date(2019, 1, 8): 10,
    ...: }
```

First we get the data into a Dataframe.

```
In [59]: new_input_data = {'date': [k for k in input_data.keys()], 'value': [v for v in input_data.values()]}

In [60]: new_input_data
Out[60]:
{'date': [datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 3),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 4),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 5),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 6),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 7),
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 8)],
 'value': [2, 2, 2, 9, 10, 10, 10]}

In [61]: df = pd.DataFrame(new_input_data)

In [62]: df
Out[62]:
         date  value
0  2019-01-01      2
1  2019-01-03      2
2  2019-01-04      2
3  2019-01-05      9
4  2019-01-06     10
5  2019-01-07     10
6  2019-01-08     10
```

Sort the dataframe by date, for good measure.

```
 df.sort_values('date', ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Next, we assign each record into a group, such that if there is a difference of more than one day between consecutive records, a new group ID is started.

```
In [77]: df['grpid'] = df.date.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()

In [78]: df
Out[78]:
         date  value  grpid
0  2019-01-01      2      1
1  2019-01-03      2      2
2  2019-01-04      2      2
3  2019-01-05      9      2
4  2019-01-06     10      2
5  2019-01-07     10      2
6  2019-01-08     10      2
```

We will now iterate through a GroupBy version of this dataframe in which we will first group by `value` and then by `grpid`. The items are are as shown below. (`group` is actually a DataFrame)

```
In [87]: for name, group in df.groupby(['value', 'grpid']):
    ...:     print(name)
    ...:     print(group.to_dict())
    ...:
(2, 1)
{'date': {0: datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)}, 'value': {0: 2}, 'grpid': {0: 1}}
(2, 2)
{'date': {1: datetime.date(2019, 1, 3), 2: datetime.date(2019, 1, 4)}, 'value': {1: 2, 2: 2}, 'grpid': {1: 2, 2: 2}}
(9, 2)
{'date': {3: datetime.date(2019, 1, 5)}, 'value': {3: 9}, 'grpid': {3: 2}}
(10, 2)
{'date': {4: datetime.date(2019, 1, 6), 5: datetime.date(2019, 1, 7), 6: datetime.date(2019, 1, 8)}, 'value': {4: 10, 5: 10, 6: 10}, 'grpid': {4: 2, 5: 2, 6
```

```
In [90]: final_list = []

In [91]: for name, group in df.groupby(['value', 'grpid']):
    ...:     group_dict = group.drop('grpid', axis=1).to_dict()
    ...:     date_dict = group_dict['date']
    ...:     value_dict = group_dict['value']
    ...:     temp_dict = {
    ...:         'from_date': list(date_dict.values())[0],
    ...:         'val': set(value_dict.values()).pop(),
    ...:         'to_date': list(date_dict.values())[-1]
    ...:     }
    ...:     final_list.append(temp_dict)
    ...:

In [92]: final_list
Out[92]:
[{'from_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
  'val': 2,
  'to_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)},
 {'from_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 3),
  'val': 2,
  'to_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 4)},
 {'from_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 5),
  'val': 9,
  'to_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 5)},
 {'from_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 6),
  'val': 10,
  'to_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 8)}]
```

Comment: @navneethc- Thanks for the solution. Actually tried it using pandas and it worked like a charm. But wanted a more naive solution without any external library.

Comment: You see, that's why you must always mention exactly what you tried in your original post. ;-)

Comment: @navneethc- Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @navneethc- I tried your code. It fails for the input 
input_data = {
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 1): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 2): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 3): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 4): 3,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 5): 3,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 6): 3,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 7): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 8): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 9): 2,
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 10): 2,
}
It should be grouping 1-3,4-6 and 7-10. Rather it groups 1-10, and 4-6